# pip error while installing django, kivy and other modules

Tags: pip

I installed python 3.10 then tried to install django but it just starts downloading by after it reaches a certain point it crashes and shows this error Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
> "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py",
> line 302, in _error_catcher
> yield   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py",
> line 384, in read
> data = self._fp.read(amt)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py",
> line 60, in read
> data = self.__fp.read(amt)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\http\client.py",
> line 447, in read
> n = self.readinto(b)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\http\client.py",
> line 491, in readinto
> n = self.fp.readinto(b)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\socket.py",
> line 589, in readinto
> return self._sock.recv_into(b)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ssl.py",
> line 1049, in recv_into
> return self.read(nbytes, buffer)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\ssl.py",
> line 908, in read
> return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer) socket.timeout: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

> File
> "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\basecommand.py",
> line 228, in main
> status = self.run(options, args)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\commands\install.py",
> line 291, in run
> resolver.resolve(requirement_set)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolve.py",
> line 103, in resolve
> self._resolve_one(requirement_set, req)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolve.py",
> line 257, in _resolve_one
> abstract_dist = self._get_abstract_dist_for(req_to_install)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\resolve.py",
> line 210, in _get_abstract_dist_for
> self.require_hashes   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\operations\prepare.py",
> line 310, in prepare_linked_requirement
> progress_bar=self.progress_bar   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\download.py",
> line 837, in unpack_url
> progress_bar=progress_bar   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\download.py",
> line 674, in unpack_http_url
> progress_bar)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\download.py",
> line 898, in _download_http_url
> _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes, progress_bar)   File
> "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\download.py",
> line 618, in _download_url
> hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\utils\hashes.py",
> line 48, in check_against_chunks
> for chunk in chunks:   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\download.py",
> line 586, in written_chunks
> for chunk in chunks:   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\utils\ui.py",
> line 159, in iter
> for x in it:   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\download.py",
> line 575, in resp_read
> decode_content=False):   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py",
> line 436, in stream
> data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py",
> line 401, in read
> raise IncompleteRead(self._fp_bytes_read, self.length_remaining)   File
> "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\contextlib.py",
> line 130, in **exit**
> self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)   File "c:\users\gabraham.aecigroup\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\urllib3\response.py",
> line 307, in _error_catcher
> raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, 'Read timed out.') pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read
> timed out.

So I tried to replace python 3.10 with version 3.7.0 but I am still getting the same error. How do I avoid this error?

Answer (score 0):

check [here](https://www.dev2qa.com/how-to-fix-the-error-socket-timeout-the-read-operation-timed-out-when-run-pip-install-command/), probably you have bad connection to internet or the download takes too long...

Comment: yeah i think i had a weak internet connection,i fixed that now its downloading...thank you very much